# Can I write a more compact rule for git add?

Tags: git

I need add into the staged area all `ini` files of current directory and its subdirectories recursively. Is exist a single filter for it?

I use it:

```
git add *.ini ./**/\*.ini
```

So I pointed two selection rules. Can I write it more compactly through a single rule?

I tried such variants: `**/\*.ini`, `./**/\*.ini`, `*/**/\*.ini` but these are not the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `git add "*.ini"`. By putting `*.ini` in quotes you avoid that your shell is expanding the pattern to only the matching file(s) in your current directory before even passing the argument to `git`.

Comment: Sure, any syntax that escapes the asterisk works ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use `find` for more complicated operations:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ini' -exec git add {} +
```